# Where Apache Spark does the compression on output?

Tags: azure, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, azure-blob-storage

We are having a Spark job that is running in standalone cluster mode and reads the data from HDFS and compresses using our custom compressor component and writes the `.zip` file to Azure blob storage. Our Spark & HDFS are hosted in the same data center(on-prem).

For instance, the Spark job is reading 8 GB file from on-prem HDFS and creating 3 GB `.zip` on Azure blob storage, in this case, does Spark copy 8 GB file to Azure blob storage and then compress it to a 3 GB `.zip` file, or does the compression happen at the executor/worker nodes and only the compressed data (3 GB) will be sent to the Azure blob storage? I wanted to understand the amount of data transfer that is happening in my case between private on-prem to Azure storage, Is it 3 GB or 8 GB?

Below is the code snippet,

```
sparkSession
      .read
      .schema(getInputSchema)
      .option("escape", "\"")
      .option("quote", "\"")
      .csv(hdfsPath)
      .write
      .repartition(1)
      .option("escape", "\"")
      .option("quote", "\"")
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("compression", "com.explore.compress.CustomZipCodec")
      .partitionBy("colum1")
      .csv(azureBlobPath)
```

Just to add, we are using `apache-spark-2.3.x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compression is programmatic and will occur on the Workers via the Executor. Thus on prem and 3gb transferred to azure.